# How to open a second window in QGIS plugin from a button inside the main window

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, pyqt

If I already created a qgis plugin, and i need to create a button inside that plugin that opens a new window, how is that possible? Qt creator won't add a slot unless there are a header file. I looked inside the plugin directory and didn't find the .h file, so I compiled it using uic, but it still can't find the .h file it says : no document matching ui_test.h could be found, rebuilding the project might help.

Comment: Please use capital letters to let others read your posts more conveniently.

Comment: Do you want an additional button in the QGIS toolbar or do you want to add a button to the plugin's dialog?

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120499/how-to-open-second-window-in-my-plugin-for-qgis